# How do I make this partition in my numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I need to partition these points.

```
[ 1] H = G.copy() # networkx graph
[ 2] broken_parts = np.zeros((r*c)) # r,c=10 in this case
[ 3] 
[ 4] v = np.where(data[:,0]<0)[0]
[ 5] broken_parts[v] += 1 # this successfully sets each entry in those specified locations to 1
[ 6] 
[ 7] H.remove_nodes_from(v) # removes the previously selected nodes
[ 8] H = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(H)
[ 9] 
[10] L, data1 = G_to_Coordinates(H,norm=True) # revises the data excluding the previously selected values
[11] 
[12] v = np.where(data1[:,0]<0)[0] # finds the next partition
[13] broken_parts[broken_parts==0][v] += 2 # fails here, but intended to set the partition in broken_parts as 2
```

Line [12] successfully finds the array positions, but `broken_parts` doesn't update with the 2s. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes had trouble when using `+=` in numpy, and also in masking sections of arrays. To be honest, I'm not sure of the reasons, or if they're causing your problem, but try these:

Change line 13 to `broken_parts = broken_parts[broken_parts==0][v] + 2`

Create single mask first:

```
mask = v && (broken_parts == 0)
broken_parts[mask] += 2
```

And both in combination.